# sqlite program works on simulator, not on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, ios-simulator, fmdb

I'm running a SQLite searching program on the iOS simulator in xcode, and it works perfectly, however, when I run it on my iPhone it gives me an error saying "error opening!: 14" I'm guessing it's the database path, but I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Comment: What is path for your database?

Comment: @VXtreme I'm using the path to it on my computer, so I don't know what path to use for the device

Comment: the database needs to be included in the target so that it is copied to the app bundle

Comment: I would bet that you're trying to access your DB from the read-only path.  The DB needs to be copied/created into the app's documents directory, or another read/write location.

Comment: @phix23 it is being copied into the bundle, I unzipped the ipa and checked.

Comment: @HotLicks the database is only meant as a read only anyway, there are only queries no updates or anything.

Comment: Pretty sure it still needs to be in read/write space.

Comment: @HotLicks how would I get it there?

Comment: @HotLicks I was wondering how to do that, but it's ok I figured it out.

Comment: +1 for figuring it out.  It's important to learn how to do this stuff for yourself, vs just looking for a "cookbook" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents path :

```
    NSArray *arrayPathComponent=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSHomeDirectory(),@"Documents",@"yourdatabasename.sqlite",nil];
destinationPath=[NSString pathWithComponents:arrayPathComponent];
```

Use this destination path for your database operation. But create your database at this  path. This will work on your device also.

Comment: Yes, the "NSSearchPathForDirectoriesinDomains" method supplied in many tutorials and examples seems to bug out for me when applied to device (OK for simulator). This method works for both device and simulator in my case.